# Can Gitlab be used as a headless CMS?

Tags: git, web, gitlab

Most [JamStack](https://jamstack.org/) architectures include a [static site generator](https://www.staticgen.com/), a [headless CMS](https://headlesscms.org/) and a git server. Thought, gitlab itself can manage wikis, tickets and templating. Is it then possible to use it as a headless CMS? How?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [Gitlab Pages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/) :

> GitLab Pages is a feature that allows you to publish static websites directly from a repository in GitLab.
>
> You can use it either for personal or business websites, such as portfolios, documentation, manifestos, and business presentations, and attribute any license to your content.

This can also be useful to you :

> To publish a website with Pages, you can use any Static Site Generator
> (SSG), such as Jekyll, Hugo, Middleman, Harp, Hexo, and Brunch, just
> to name a few. You can also publish any website written directly in
> plain HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Comment: No, you do not answer the question

Comment: So please try to be more explicit.

Comment: Hi there @AndreDS, I'd say OP is not asking whether Gitlab can be used as a frontend solution, which would be GitLab Pages, but as a backend headless CMS, so that one can retrieve content from it as with others headless CMS that exist